# Regular Expression for removing quotes from around numeric values in a string in ColdFusion 9

Tags: regex, json, coldfusion

By a numeric value I mean a value in the following JSON that should not be contained within double quotes. I've written a one-off workaround for this but a generic REReplace() that can be re-used would be a fantastic help.

So this

```
{
  "collapse_key" : "demo",
  "delay_while_idle" : true,
  "registration_ids" : ["xyz"],
  "data" : {
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : "value2",
  },
  "time_to_live" : "3"
},
```

becomes this:

```
{
  "collapse_key" : "demo",
  "delay_while_idle" : true,
  "registration_ids" : ["xyz"],
  "data" : {
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : "value2",
  },
  "time_to_live" : 3
},
```

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that if this code only needs to run on ColdFusion (not Railo or OpenBD) then it can also be solved with `serializeJson(deserializeJson(s))` - at least in current versions; not sure I'd want to rely on the behaviour, but useful to know about.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
s = reReplace(s, '"([\d.-]+)"', "\1", "ALL")
```

(Where s is your JSON string)

- " matches a double quote
- () says "remember this so I can reference it later as \1
- \d means "a digit"
- . means a decimal point
- - means a minus sign
- + means one or more of them

Note that this will match illegitimate "numbers" like "..0-1", but within the scope of your requirement, this is probably fine.  One could convolute the regex to be more precise, but there is perhaps no gain from doing so here.  Let me know if there's a false-positive risk here, and I can amend.

Or I imagine Peter is about to give a better answer anyhow ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately I was asleep at the time, which of course wouldn't normally stop me answering, but my computer was off. ;)  Anyhow, since `-` can only occur once at the start, an easy/painless improvement is `"(-?[\d.]+)"`, and a longer winded version would be `"(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)"` - which is a bit ugly and does makes me wonder why we don't yet have the ability to specify common sub-patterns as named entities.

Comment: (That second one is still not perfect - doesn't match stuff like `"-.5"` and incorrectly matches `"size: 6\"4"` - but it's _probably_ good enough given the limited info provided.)